# How to put a '-' in between every item of a sequence?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that consist of integer sequences. For example the following two sequences:

```
2 2 0 -2
1 0 2 1 1 -2
```

Now, the end of every sequence needs to be -2 and in between every item in the sequence I need to get a '-1' so the outcome would be like this:

```
2 -1 2 -1 0 -1 -2
1 -1 0 -1 2 -1 1 -1 1 -1 -2
```

This is how the dataframe looks like:

```
       sequences
0           2 -2
1           2 -2
2           2 -2
3         2 2 -2
4           2 -2
...          ...
488700      2 -2
488701      2 -2
488702      2 -2
488703    2 2 -2
488704      2 -2

[488705 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: You might want to add a [pandas] tag and fix the title of your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Can you clarify your expected output for the dataframe you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to 100% undersand the need, but here is a suggestion

```
d = [ "2 -2",
      "2 0 -2",
      "0 0 0 2 -2"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns= ['sequences'] )

df.sequences = df.sequences.apply(lambda x: ' -1 '.join(x.split()))
```